# Difference in using create vite@latest vs create-next-app vs create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vite

I know that using create react-app is much slower than using create vite@latest and that using create next-app specifies you want to use the next.js framework, but what about using create vite@latest vs create next-app. Is create-next-app also slower than create vite@latest? and can I use create vite@latest first and then install the next.js framework? because I only see examples of next.js being used when react apps are initialized with create next-app

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, vite and next.js are not compatible. Because next.js has a strong dependency on webpack, webpack and vite have similar roles. You can't use them at the same time.

For the foreseeable future, vite and next.js cannot be used together. However, next.js is also currently shipping a [new compiler](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-12#faster-builds-and-fast-refresh-with-rust-compiler) that claims to meet or exceed the speed of vite.